# Callbacks for pdf creation DataTables.net to display a wait indicator

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I am using [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/) to create a PDF from an HTML table.

Is there a way to add some sort of callback / promise for PDF create (or other export)? Some tables have 3,000+ rows and it would be great if I could show the user a "Working" modal or some other progress bar during the generation. I can't seem to find any sort of notification for PDF Started and Ended.

Here is what I am using to create the PDF

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    tableData.DataTable({
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                orientation: 'landscape',
                pageSize: 'A4',
                alignment: "center",
                customize : function(doc) {

                    //Show some working modal?

                    doc.pageMargins = [10, 10, 10,10 ];
                    doc.content[2].table.widths = Array(doc.content[2].table.body[0].length + 1).join('*').split('');
                },
            }
        ]
    })
} );
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `.on( 'draw' )` event of datatables ( or one fo the other event hooks ) ? Can you hook that to the pdf plugin?

Answer (score 0):

dataTables.net has no out-of-the-box callbacks or functions to know when a PDF creation started and when it's finished. They planned on adding it, but they haven't so far.

Source: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/33270/is-it-possible-to-show-a-spinner-while-a-pdf-is-created-with-pdfhtml5